# Combining CLI parameters into a single string

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

For a given command and parameters which can be passed to it, are the following always equivalent

`mycommand -a -b`

`mycommand -ab`

`mycommand -ba`

What if a parameter requires a value, e.g. `mycommand -a -b 32M`

would `mycommand -ab 32M` and/or `mycommand -ba 32M` work?

Thank you

Comment: The argument should stay after the parameter that requires it. `mycommand -ab 32M` should be the same as `mycommand -a -b 32M` and `mycommand -ba 32M` should be the same as `mycommand -b -a 32M`. But if both `-a` and `-b` require argument they cannot be combined. The recommended way is to accept combining only the parameters without arguments.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense; I was just wondering if there was a documentation for this sort of a thing